# Возможно ли наследование class <---> struct в c++?

Tags: c++, классы

Насколько я понимаю, они оба поддерживают наследование, оба могут содержать поля и функции, оба могут содержать конструктор и деструктор, оба поддерживают наследование. Разница в том, что функции и переменные без ключевого слова private/protected/public одним по умолчанию отправляются в раздел private, другим в раздел public.
Возможно ли наследование struct из родителя class и наоборот? Если да, то каким образом будут преобразованы поля без модификатора? Например, отправляя из class в дочерний struct они останутся private или станут public? Если нет, то почему нет? Наследование имею ввиду полное, модификатор наследования public.

Comment: По идее, раньше struct трактовалась как class у которого все поля public. Если концепция не поменялась, то наследовать можно.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Не все, а те, которые объявлены без модификатора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наследование возможно.

Члены `struct` ведут себя так, как будто в начале определения `struct` стоит неявный спецификатор доступа `public`, а члены `class` - как будто в начале определения стоит неявный спецификатор доступа `private`

```
struct S
{
  // public:
  ...
};

class C
{
  // private:
  ...
};
```

При наследовании, если наследник является `struct`, то наследование выполняется как `public` по умолчанию. Если наследник является `class`, то наследование выполняется как `private` по умолчанию.

```
struct DS : Parent // эквивалентно `struct DS : public Parent`
{
  ...
};

class DC : Parent // эквивалентно `class DC : private Parent`
{
  ...
};
```

А далее работают одни и те же общие правила, единые и для `class`, и для `struct`: более ограничивающий уровень доступа "побеждает" более расслабленный уровень доступа.

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку `struct` - это `class` с `public` **по умолчанию**, действуют все те же правила, как если бы это был класс, члены которого объявлены как `public` - понятно, те, которые объявлены **без модификатора**. Члены, объявленные с модификатором, ведут себя точно так же, как если бы этот тип был объявлен как `class`.

Надеюсь, описывать правила доступа при наследовании тут не нужно? :) А то можно не успеть их закончить в 2018 году :)